# A generalization of IMO 1977 problem 2

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Here is the IMO 1977 problem 2:

> In a finite sequence of real numbers the sum of any seven successive terms is
>   negative, and the sum of any eleven successive terms is positive. Determine
>   the maximum number of terms in the sequence.

I would like to generalize this problem : seven -> $p$; eleven -> $q$. I have read that the result is $p+q-1-\gcd(p,q)$, I wonder how to prove it. Firstly, we shall assume that $\gcd(p,q)=1$. I proved that the number of terms is less than $p+q-2$, but I still have to prove that it can be equal to $p+q-2$. Can you exhibit an example?

Remark. It is sufficient to prove that the following square matrix is invertible:
$\newcommand{\block}[1]{
  \underbrace{1 \cdots 1}_{#1}
}$
$$\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
  \smash[b]{\block{p}} \\
&\ddots \\
& & \block{p}\\
\smash[b]{\block{q}} \\
&\ddots \\
& & \block{q}
  \end{pmatrix}
}_{p+q-2}$$

Comment: An example of what?  For $p=7,q=11 : \{5,5,-13,5,5,5,-13,5,5,-13,5,5,5,-13,5,5\}$.

Comment: I meant an example of working sequence with p+q-2 terms in the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has a very simple resolution if we replace the terms $(u_k)_{k=1}^n$ by the sums $s_k=\sum_1^ku_i$ for $0 \le k \le n$ (with $s_0=0)$. Then the conditions become:

$s_{k+7} < s_k$ for $0 \le k \le n-7$

$s_{k+11} > s_k$ for $0 \le k \le n-11$

So if $n \ge 17$, we have

$0 = s_0 < s_7<s_{14}<s_{3} <s_{10} <s_{17}<s_{6}<s_{13}<s_{2}<s_{9}<s_{16}<s_5<s_{12}<s_1 <s_{8} <s_{15} <s_{4} <s_{11} <s_0 = 0,$

a contradiction. As a bonus, we immediately get a maximal-length sequence from this. Omitting the term $s_{17}$ gives:

$s_{6}<s_{13}<s_{2}<s_{9}<s_{16}<s_5<s_{12}<s_1 <s_{8} <s_{15} <s_{4} <s_{11} <0 < s_7<s_{14}<s_{3} <s_{10}$

Set these equal to consecutive integers:

$s_6=-12,s_{13}=-11,\ldots,s_{11}=-1,s_7=1,\ldots,s_3=3,s_{10}=4$

Now just read off the values of $u_k$ from $u_k=s_k-s_{k-1}$ to get

$\{5,5,−13,5,5,5,−13,5,5,−13,5,5,5,−13,5,5\}$

This works for any $p,q$ with $(p,q)=1$. Just write down

$s_{p-1} < \ldots < s_q < 0 < s_p < \ldots < s_{q-1}$

and assign consecutive integers to the terms. For instance, with $p=9, q=5$, we get

$s_8 < s_3 < s_{12} < s_7 < s_2 < s_{11} < s_6 < s_1 < s_{10} < s_5 < 0 < s_9 < s_4$

So we put $s_8=-10,\ldots,s_4=2,$ and get

$\{-3,-3,-3,11,-3,-3,-3,-3,11,-3,-3,-3\}$

Comment: It seems a good approach, but I need some explanations about the general case : why is it possible to write $s_{p−1}<…<s_q<0<s_p<…<s_{q−1}$, whith all the terms $s_0,...,s_{p+q-2}$.

Comment: Ok, I finally got it, it is not very diificult to show that it works in the general case.

Comment: can you please show that the sequence you have developed will never give a contradiction?

Answer (score 3):

I explain below an algorithmic construction which achieves the unique
solution to the problem obtained when one adds the further constraint
that all the consecutive $p$-sums be equal to $+1$ and all the consecutive
$q$-sums equal to $-1$. The algorithm is simple enough (although the
details are a little messy to write out), uses the Euclidean
algorithm and reminds one of the Cantor set construction. I do not know
if a simpler solution exists.

As you suggest, let us assume ${\sf gcd}(p,q)=1$. We may assume without loss that $p<q$. If you apply the Euclidean algorithm to the integers $p$ and
$q$, you obtain an increasing sequence $c_0=0<c_1=1<c_2<c_3< \ldots <c_{m-1}=p<c_m=q$ such that for every
$i$, $c_{i+1}$ is congruent to $c_{i-1}$ modulo $c_i$. We call such 
sequences $C$-sequences. The case $p=1$ is trivial, so we may assume 
$m\geq 3$. For any positive integers $i,j$, denote by
$\rho_i(j)$ the unique integer in $\lbrace 1,2, \ldots ,i\rbrace$
that’s congruent to $j$ modulo $i$. Also, define an equivalence
relation $\sim_i$ on integers by letting $x \sim_i y$ iff the two 
numbers $x$ and $y$ are both equal to $i$ or both not 
equal to $i$.

**Fundamental lemma** Let  $c_0=0<c_1=1<c_2<\ldots <c_m$ be a
$C$-sequence with $m\geq 3$. Then, for any $x\in[1,c_{m-1}-2]$ we have

$$
\rho_{c_2}\rho_{c_3}\ldots \rho_{c_{m-2}}\rho_{c_{m-1}}(x)
\sim_{c_2} \rho_{c_2}\rho_{c_3}\ldots \rho_{c_{m-2}}\rho_{c_{m-1}}(x+c_m) \tag{1}
$$

**Proof of fundamental lemma** By induction on $m$. When $m=3$, (1) reduces
to $ (**) : \rho_{c_2}(x) \sim_{c_2} \rho_{c_2}(x+c_3)$. Since $x\in [1,c_{2}-2]$, we have
$\rho_{c_2}(x)=x$, so that (**) is equivalent to 
$$\rho_{c_2}(x+c_3)\neq c_2 \Leftrightarrow c_2\not| x+c_3 
\Leftrightarrow c_2\not| x+c_1 \Leftrightarrow c_2\not| x+1 \tag{2}$$
and the rightmost condition is certainly true since $x+1\in[2,c_{2}-1]$.

Next, suppose that $m\geq 4$ and that the lemma is true at level $m-1$. Let 
$c_0=0<c_1<c_2<\ldots <c_m$ be a $C$-sequence and let $x\in[1,c_{m-1}-2]$. By hypothesis,
there is an integer $a$ with $c_m=ac_{m-1}+c_{m-2}$, so that to show (1) it will
suffice to show the following :

$$
\rho_{c_2}\rho_{c_3}\ldots \rho_{c_{m-2}}\rho_{c_{m-1}}(x)
\sim_{c_1} \rho_{c_2}\rho_{c_3}\ldots \rho_{c_{m-2}}\rho_{c_{m-1}}(x+c_{m-2}) \tag{3}
$$

Note that $\rho_{c_{m-1}}(x)=x$. If $x \leq c_{m-1}-c_{m-2}$, then  we have
 $\rho_{c_{m-1}}(x+c_{m-2})=x+c_{m-2}$, so that 
 $\rho_{c_{m-2}}\rho_{c_{m-1}}(x)=\rho_{c_{m-2}}\rho_{c_{m-1}}(x+c_{m-2})$, and we see
 that the two numbers in (3) are equal. We may therefore assume that $x>c_{m-1}-c_{m-2}$ ;
 in that case, $y=x-(c_{m-1}-c_{m-2})$ satisfies $y\in[1,c_{m-2}-2]$, and (3)
 can be simplified to

$$
\rho_{c_1}\rho_{c_2}\ldots \rho_{c_{m-2}}(y+c_{m-1}-c_{m-2})
\sim_{c_1} \rho_{c_1}\rho_{c_2}\ldots \rho_{c_{m-2}}(y) \tag{4}
$$ 
  But $\rho_{c_{m-2}}(y+c_{m-1}-c_{m-2})=\rho_{c_{m-2}}(y+c_{m-1})$, so that (4)
  follows from the induction hypothesis at level $m-1$. This concludes the proof 
   of the lemma by induction.

Once we have our lemma, say that an integer $x\in [1,p+q-2]$ is good if
$\rho_{c_2}\ldots \rho_{c_{m-2}}\rho_{c_{m-1}}(x) =c_2$.  Say that
$x$ is bad if it is not good. The lemma then shows that if any two numbers in the interval $I=[1,p+q-2]$  are  congruent
modulo $p$ or $q$, then they are both bad or both good. It follows that fro any $x\in[0,p+q-2]$, all the
subintervals of length $x$ in $I$ contain the same numbers of good elements (call it
$g(x)$). It follows from the fundamental lemma that

$$
g(qc_i+r)=qg(c_i)+g(r) \ \text{whenever} 0\leq r<c_i, qc_i+r\leq c_{i+1}. \tag{5}
$$

Let $i\geq 2$. There is an integer $a_i$ such that $c_i=a_ic_{i-1}+c_{i-2}$. By (5) we have
$g(c_i)=a_ig(c_{i-1})+g(c_{i-2})$, and hence

$$
c_{i-1}g(c_i)-c_ig(c_{i-1})=-(c_{i-2}g(c_{i-1})-c_{i-1}g(c_{i-2})) \tag{6}
$$

In other words $\delta_{i+1}=-\delta_i$ where $\delta_i=c_{i-1}g(c_i)-c_ig(c_{i-1})$.
As $\delta_2=1$ we deduce $\delta_i=(-1)^i$. Next, define a 
sequence $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{p+q-2})$ by

$$
a_{x}=\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lcl}
 \frac{p+q-(g(p)+g(q))}{qg(p)-pg(q)}=\frac{p+q-(g(p)+g(q))}{(-1)^{m+1}} & \rm if & x \ \text{is good} \\
-\frac{g(p)+g(q)}{qg(p)-pg(q)}=\frac{g(p)+g(q)}{(-1)^m} & \rm if & x \ \text{is bad}
\end{array}\right. \tag{7}
$$

This sequence has the property that the sum of any successive $p$ elements is $1$,
and  the sum of any successive $q$ elements is $-1$.

Comment: First, thank you for this detailed proof. Yet, what if $qg_p=pg_q$?

Comment: @Papagon Please see the latest version of my answer.